# error while trying to add android platform with ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

When running the command `ionic cordova add platform android` I am getting the following error.

I've completely uninstalled Nodejs and reinstalled Ionic and Cordova globally from scratch but I can not figure out why this error is occurring.

The error also occurs when I execute the command `cordova -v`

```
cordova.cmd platform add android --save
C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: wmic os get Caption
Description = O servi�o n�o pode ser iniciado porque est� desativado ou n�o tem dispositivos ativados associados.

    at makeError (C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:34:24)
    at osName (C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:26:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

This error occurs every time I run the command, I can not add the Android platform. I need to run `ionic cordova run android` to open in my emulator I created in Android Studio.

```
 npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\LUIZ\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@8.0.2
+-- cordova@9.0.0
`-- ionic@5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, but I had to:

```
Windows-Key (Keyboard)
System Environment Variable 
Environmentsvariables.. 
Select Path Variable and edit
Add the path to your wbem
example: c:\Windows\System32\wbem
Restart cmd
Enjoy
```